# Have do display the content of the left navigation link in the body and beneath the link for Mobile in Adobe AEM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, adobe, aem

I do have a requirement to create a responsive component using Adobe Cq5/AEM and Bootstrap .
I have a left navigation which has multiple links and upon clicking on the link the message related to the link has to be displayed in the body.

But for Mobile it has to be displayed underneath the Link.

Not sure if it has to be achieved using Adobe AEM or Bootstrap, if so how to achieve that..

Your help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This is something you will do with Bootstrap classes, it's not something in AEM itself.

It's hard to give a direct solution without seeing how the end result should look like though, but you will need to use a combination of javascript (which I'm guessing you already use to fill the main body with the message) and Bootstrap classes.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

What you can do is to have a secondary body div that you will only display in SM or XS (or which ever size you want it to display)

If you are not using javascript to fill the body, but they are hidden by default and you show them based on the link clicked, then all you need to do is have 2 sets of them, one for mobile, one for desktop. You should be able to use collapsible divs for this on mobile.

Make sure that one of them is set to not be read by Screen Readers if Accessibility is a concern.